# Doctrine 2 HAVING on a alias fails in a subquery

Tags: mysql, doctrine-orm, dql

I have a query which works fine on its own. But when using it as a subquery it somehow fails to recognize the alias, instead, the parser thinks it belongs to a class.

To explain what im trying to achieve:

Lets say for example we have a Hotel with Rooms(each room is a different type) and we only want the Hotels that contains specific room types.

A WHERE in a JOIN would work, but that would only JOIN the Rooms that match the criteria. I want Hotels that match the criteria but still select all the rooms.
This is your every day SQL solution so i figured im probably doing something wrong..

**Example root query:**

```
$main = $em->createQueryBuilder()
  ->select('hotels, rooms')
  ->from('Hotel', 'hotels')
  ->leftJoin('hotels.Rooms', 'rooms');
```

**Subquery:**

```
$sub = $em->createQueryBuilder()
  ->select('count(rooms.id) as hidden totalRooms')
  ->from('HotelToRoom', 'rooms')
  ->andWhere('rooms.hotel_id = hotels.id') // or a dummy ID as a solo query..
  ->andWhere($qb->expr()->in('rooms.type_id', implode(',', $types)))
  ->having('totalRooms = ?1')
  ->setParameter('1', count($types))
;
```

The subquery works fine solo. But when I add it as a subquery like:

```
$main->andWhere($qb->expr()->exists($sub->getDQL()));
```

The following error erupts:

```
Error: Class 'totalRooms' is not defined.'
```

It seems that the having part no longer searches inside the subquery or something...?

Comment: try to change `as hidden totalRooms` to `as totalRooms`

Comment: doesn't make a difference, it's just a keyword to disable injecting the alias into your model

Comment: I'm not familiarized with this Doctrine framework, but if it works as a sql it should work with: `->having('count(rooms.id) = ?1')`

Comment: DQL just looks like SQL :)